# Electricity and Dust

Tags: electricity

My question is, does an electrically charged material attract dust?

Would it be possible to make a device like a vacuum cleaner based on a mechanism like this (in principle)?

Comment: Do you mean this kind of device: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_precipitator ?

Comment: @GuoQianyi that looks exactly like what OP is looking for! If you could write a bit more about the mechanism of operation, you could (and should) post it as an answer!

Comment: I am wondering whether a device similar to (http://www.irobot.com/us/learn/home/roomba.aspx) can be built except instead of a vacuum for cleaning, the device uses some sort of electricity to attract the dust.

Answer (score 4):

An electrostatic precipitator (ESP) is a highly efficient filtration device that removes fine particles, like dust and smoke, from a flowing gas using the force of an induced electrostatic charge minimally impeding the flow of gases through the unit. [[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatic_precipitator)]

[image: Conceptual diagram of an electrostatic precipitator]
Credit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Electrostatic_precipitator.svg (CC-BY-SA 3.0)

Answer (score 2):

If you have a polarizable material (like a dust mote) in an electric field, your material will develop an [electric dipole moment](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/dipole.html).

An electric dipole in an electric field feels a force $\vec F = -\vec\nabla(\vec d \cdot \vec E)$.  This has the net effect of attracting polarizable objects to regions of stronger electric field.

There are filtration systems that are based on this phenomenon (as indicated in a comment on your question), but your design must take into account that the strength of the force falls off *very* quickly with distance.